# Configuration for loading story from String?

Tags: jbehave

I have a web service posting Gherkins stories to a back-end and would like to load those stories into configuration as a string without having to save them as a file.

Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your custoom story loader that will collect stories from the web service and pass them to JBehave.
You need also use a GherkinStoryParser to translate stories from Gherking format to JBehave format.

An example configuration might look like in the following example.
**A custom story loader** that retrieves stories from a map of strings:

```
public class MyStoryLoader implements StoryLoader {

    private Map<String,String> stories;

    public MyStoryLoader( Map<String,String> storiesToLoad){
        this.stories = storiesToLoad;
    }

    public String loadStoryAsText(String storyName) {
        return stories.get( storyName );
    }
}
```

**Some class that collects stories from the web service and return them as a map with unique story names and story bodies:**

```
public class StoryCollectorFromWebService {

    private final static String storyTemplate = "Feature: A story that is saved in the string\n"
            + "\n"
            + "Scenario: Read the scenario from the string\n"
            + "\n"
            + "Given There is some story named ${name} saved in the string\n"
            + "When I run this story named ${name}\n"
            + "Then I can see it's results";

    // This is a method that collects stories from the Web Service and saves them in a map of strings
    public Map<String,String> getStoriesFromWebService(){

        Map<String,String> storiesFromWebService = new HashMap<String,String>();

        String storyNames[] = {"A","B","C","ABC","Some story", "Another story"};

        for(String storyName: storyNames)
            storiesFromWebService.put( storyName, storyTemplate.replace("${name}", storyName));

        return storiesFromWebService;
    }
}
```

**and sample configuration to run these stories using our StoryLoader and GherkinStoryParser:**

```
public class RunAs_JUnitStories extends JUnitStories {

    public RunAs_JUnitStories() {
        configuredEmbedder().embedderControls().doGenerateViewAfterStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInStories(true)
                .doIgnoreFailureInView(true).useThreads(1).useStoryTimeoutInSecs(60);
    }

    Map<String,String> storiesFromWebService = new StoryCollectorFromWebService().getStoriesFromWebService();

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new ArrayList<String>( storiesFromWebService.keySet());       
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
        ParameterConverters parameterConverters = new ParameterConverters();
        ExamplesTableFactory examplesTableFactory = new ExamplesTableFactory(new LocalizedKeywords(), new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass), parameterConverters);
        parameterConverters.addConverters(new DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                new ExamplesTableConverter(examplesTableFactory));

        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            // Use custom story loader
            .useStoryLoader(new MyStoryLoader( storiesFromWebService ))
            // Use Gherkin parser 
            .useStoryParser( new GherkinStoryParser() )
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                .withDefaultFormats()
                .withMultiThreading(true)
                .withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT, HTML, XML))
            .useParameterConverters(parameterConverters);
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new MySteps());
    }   
}
```

---

Here is a link to a working example: https://github.com/kordirko/TestJBB

You can try import it into Eclipse and play with it, but I apologize if something goes wrong,
It's my first project on github, I'am still learning how to do it :)

Comment: I just ended up creating a private inner class that extends LoadFromClasspath and overrides loadResourceAsText() but this is definitely a formal approach.

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/foofactory/f50c7f1d3df7853395e4).